# How to return image saved in database (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, download

So I'm trying to make a upload route to save in a database.I done it, but now I want to return this image (To can see it and if I wish download) in another route and flask return me this error:"name 'send_file' is not defined". What I'm doing wrong ? Is there a better way to do it ?

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
        
    if request.method == "POST":

        if not allowed_image_size(request.cookies.get("filesize")):
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['image']
        comentaries = request.form['comentaries']

        if not allowed_image(file.filename):
            return('No valid extencion')
            #return redirect(request.url
        else: 
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

        newFile = FileContent(client_name=current_user.username, comments=comentaries, data=file.read())
        db.session.add(newFile)
        db.session.commit() 
        return 'Saved ' + file.filename + ' to the database'    
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    file_data = FileContent.query.all()
    return send_file(BytesIO(file_data.data), attachment_filname='egreso.jpg', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: did you do `from flask import send_file` https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: I think your general approach is correct. The hint from python_user to check the imports makes sense to me. I also notice that you are asking for all entries from FileContent and not just one.

Comment: So, you recomend me somethink like this: "file_data = FileContent.query.filter_by(name=name).all() ?

Comment: I think you just want to query one database entry. 
If you use ```.all()``` a list will be returned. 
A function like ```.first()``` would be more appropriate.
Which criteria you use to filter depends on your database scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The error you face says `"name 'send_file' is not defined"`.

This mentions that you should import the `send_file` function from `flask` like:

```
from flask import send_file
```